# What happens inside MySQL when I execute an INSERT?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

Lets say I write a query like `"INSERT INTO my_table (a,b) VALUES (1,2)"`. 
What happens inside MySQL from the time client passes the query till it saved on disk.

Like:

```
-> What all innodb objects(filesystem buffers/logs) affected? 
-> What're the step the data has to pass through till it reaches on table space?
```

In another word, anatomy of db writes.

For example:

```
-> query being parsed by the parser
-> correct data page be loaded to innodb_buffer_pool
-> data being changed(dirty pages), and changes are logged to redo log buffer
-> entry on undo logs(rollback segment)
-> on commit, redo log buffer flushed to redo logfile
-> binary logging happens(if enabled)
-> dirty pages write to double write buffer
-> Finally it flushed to disk.
```

I am sure people has better ways/answer to explain the sequence.

Comment: Hint.. use query profiling ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html )  FULL on a INSERT query.. and you can see where the query is executing the MySQL source code.. Use the MySQL source code en see what happens...

Answer (score 6):

*This assumes InnoDB, not any other Engine*...

You have some of the basics.  Here are some more.

```
-> Query received by Server
-> query being parsed by the parser
-> "open" table (if not already open)
-> check for "strict mode" errors
-> Hand off the query from "Handler" to "Engine".  (The rest assumes `ENGINE=InnoDB`)
-> If part of a transaction, ...
-> If autocommitting, ...
-> If `AUTO_INCREMENT, ...
-> If `INSERT` included `PRIMARY KEY` columns, ...
-> If neither of above, create hidden AI value, ...
-> Execute `BEFORE TRIGGERs`, if any
-> Given the PK, drill down the BTree to find the location.
-> Check for Duplicate Key -- PK and any relevant UNIQUE keys.
-> obtain eXclusive lock on the row -- (maybe gap lock?)
-> correct data page be loaded to innodb_buffer_pool (if not already cached)
-> If adding this row would overflow the block, "split" the block
-> Mark block(s) "dirty" (so it will _eventually_ be flushed to disk)
-> changes are logged to redo log
-> entry on undo logs(rollback segment)
-> Secondary index changes (if any) go into Change Buffer -- possibly triggering flush to make room
-> Execute `AFTER TRIGGERs`, if any
-> (if Galera involved) Write to gcache; coordinate with other nodes
-> if autocommit, redo log buffer flushed to redo logfile
-> deal with "group commit"?
-> binary logging happens(if enabled) -- or is this before COMMIT?
-> dirty pages write to double write buffer
-> If the Query Cache is enabled (and this is a write), invalidate all QC entries for the table(s) modified.
-> release eXclusive lock
-> success or failure returned to client
-> The block containing the row will be flushed to disk _later_
-> Index block updates will be done _later_ (cached read, apply Change Buffer, cached write, plus remove from CB)
```

I think there are a lot more details.  And I am vague on the exact order.

The files that are touched *sooner or later* include

- `.frm` to get schema (cached) (readonly)
- `ibdata1` or `.ibd` -- the 'tablespace' for data and for any modified indexes.  (read-modify-write) (cf `innodb_file_per_table`)
- doublewrite buffer (write)
- `iblog*` (write)

This does not include "temp" tables that are created in some complex `SELECTs`; "metadata" locks for things like `ALTER TABLE`, etc, etc.

Comment: Would it possible to add the following info into your answer ? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7ae6fb196060e617336187dbd473dc2c

Comment: @iSR5 - That link is focused on a `SELECT`.  This question is specifically for a plain `INSERT`, which only invalidates some of the QC, and probably does not need any Optimization.  (I added mention of the QC, but don't know where it belongs.  Also handoff to Engine.)

Comment: Oh, that might be different story,even if the cycle will be applied on all queries, INSERT, UPDATE, TRUNCATE, and DELETE  have more  exceptions and conditions.  As I know this will flush the query cache because the tables have been changed, but it'll go to parser and do the rest cycle with applied conditions. Some conditions may bypass some stages others won't.

Comment: @iSR5 - I left out a lot of `SELECT` stages; your link included some of them.  `TRUNCATE` is not quite like `DELETE`; it is more of a DDL than DML.  `ALTER`, `DROP`, etc, are in yet another category.  `SHOW`, `EXPLAIN`, etc, are different, too.  The full answer would take a book, not a short forum Answer.

Comment: There could be BEFORE/AFTER INSERT triggers to be fired as well. Where's the part about the statement could at some point be killed if it waits innodb_lock_wait_timeout to obtain locks, or killed as the victim of a deadlock? (+10)

Comment: Added triggers, but not sure of location; can anyone help with ordering?  I did not include any timeouts, kills, aborts, error cases, etc.  Yikes!  Even with one-liners, this is a long list.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 will change some things.  For example, the `.frm` file is gone; instead the 'Data Dictionary' is involved.